# Scroll To Item UICollectionView with UIButton programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uibutton, nsindexpath

I'm having a moment of confusion and I can't solve a very simple thing.

My CollectionView has 50 cells and I would like to scroll back and forth between the cells using a "Next" button and a "Back" button. I am aware of the scrollToItemAtIndexPath method but I have problems finding the right IndexPath .. Someone can help me ?

This is my Code:

```
// My personal method

-(void)scrollYearAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0];
    [_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
}

// Show Next Items
-(void)didScrollNextYear {
    [self scrollYearAtIndex:????];
}

// Show Previous Items
-(void)didScrollPreviousYear {
    [self scrollYearAtIndex:????];
}
```

Comment: Do you can your next/previous logic to work on currently visible cell or currently selected cell?

Comment: All Visible cell :)

Answer (score 4):

I've given the answer in `Swift`. You can write the same logic in `Objective-C`.

To get the next `indexPath`, get the `last` `indexPath` of the sorted `indexPathsForVisibleItems` array and increment by 1.

To get the previous `indexPath`, get the `first` `indexPath` of the sorted `indexPathsForVisibleItems` array and decrement by 1.

```
func didScrollNextYear() {
    if let index = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.sorted().last?.row {
        let nextIndex = index+1
        if nextIndex < self.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: nextIndex, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func didScrollPreviousYear() {
    if let index = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.sorted().first?.row {
        let previousIndex = index-1
        if previousIndex >= 0 {
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: previousIndex, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] firstObject];
it's correct in ObjC ??     if let index = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.sorted(). first?.row

Comment: Sort the `indexPathsForVisibleItems` and sort them in ascending order. Also you need `firstObject` for previous and `lastObject` for next.

Comment: I'm trying this way but I'm still crashing.....

NSArray *indexPaths = [_collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"row" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *orderedIndexPaths = [[indexPaths sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]] lastObject];

Answer (score 1):

```
let indexPaths : NSArray = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
let indexPath : NSIndexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
```

This will give you current selected index path. In `didScrollNextYear` method, increment indexPath.row by one. And in `didScrollPreviousYear`, decrement indexPath.row by one.

Sample code:

> ```
> // Show Next Items
> -(void)didScrollNextYear {
>     let indexPaths : NSArray = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
>     let indexPath : NSIndexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
>
>     [self scrollYearAtIndex: indexPath.row+1];
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion (maybe I misunderstood myself) .. this way I can only navigate between the previous and the next starting from the selected cell .. I need the user to scroll through all the cells Next / Back without considering the selected one

Comment: @kAiN: You can get the index of visible cell by let index = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.sorted().last?.row .  Understand the logic, you just need to get the index only, rest you can increment/decrement based on business condition